# Finding the distance between the tangent and normal line of a function at y=0

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

It doesn't seem difficult at first but I think the reason why I can't seem to figure this problem out is because I am used to figuring out tangents and normals at a certain point while in this problem it doesn't state at which point the tangent and normal line intersect.

Here is the assignment: 
Prove that the length of the segment that is cut off from the x-axis by the normal and tangent line of the following function is 2a (a=const). The function is:
$$ x=2a\left(\ln\left(\sin t\right)-\sin ^2 t\right)$$

$$\:y=a \sin 2t $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be any random point on the curve $y=f(x)$ where tangent and normal are drawn.

$X_t=$ point where tangent cuts $X$ axis.

$X_n=$ point where normal cuts $X$ axis.

Check that

> $X_t=x_0-{y_0\over y'(x_0)}$ and $X_n=x_0+y_0\cdot y'(x_0)\implies X_n-X_t=y_0\left(y'(x_0)+{1\over y'(x_0)}\right)$

Now $$y'(x)={dy\over dx}={dy\over dt}\cdot{dt\over dx}={2a\cos(2t)\over 2a\left({\cos(t)\over \sin(t)}-2\sin(t)\cos(t)\right)}=\tan(t)$$

$$\therefore X_N-X_t=2a\sin(2t_0)\left(\tan(t_0)+{1\over \tan(t_0)}\right)=2a$$
BINGO!

Comment: hmm interesting. I've never thought of it this way. Isn't Xn supposed to equal $$X_n=x_0-y_0\cdot y'(x_0)$$ though? Or I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: @intersomnium $$0-y_0=-{1\over y'(x_0)}(X_n-x_0)$$

Comment: Of course. :) Thank you for the help. I think I might have just one more question that might sound a little bit stupid but why do we write 0-y instead of the other way around?

Comment: @intersomnium What is the formula of a line with solpe $\eta$ at **point** $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: because when dealing with X we take the larger value and subtract the smaller so that we get a positive difference? Why doesn't the same apply to Y? I know that the equation states $$y-y_{_0}=f\:'\left(x\right)\left(x-x_0\right)$$ I hope you understand  what my logic fails to grasp..

Comment: @intersomnium WHO GAVE YOU THE UNDERSTANDING THAT **WE TAKE THE LARGER VALUE AND SUBTRACT**?

Comment: hahah, terrible math teachers in high school.

Comment: I can see that you got frustrated with my ignorance and I completely understand since I deal with it everyday when it comes to math. I will figure it out from here on my own. Thank you very much, you really did help a lot.

Comment: @intersomnium I being a math student believe: NO MATH TEACHER can ever give such a statement!. If he/she gives, he/she isn't a a MATH teacher!

Comment: @intersomnium Feel free to ask questions.. I will be glad to answer, no matter how silly they seem. Only take care: you yourself must give (and show ) a sufficient try before asking here.

Comment: I only post questions here after I have already wasted more than an hour trying to solve a problem, or multiple similar problems and haven't gotten any results. Since I don't get proper education from the institutions, I rely on the internet and the people on this site to help me when I'm stuck. I know sometimes my questions seem basic but it's because I'm trying to understand, even though I am not very good at this subject.

Comment: @intersomnium I am not discouraging you in your trying to learn things from internet, but PROPER EDUCATION from the institution is a must! As only internet wont get you anywhere!

Comment: That idea is nice but as you might deduce that I am not the one calling the shots on the quality of education in my country.

Comment: @intersomnium Wish you BEST OF LUCK in your endeavor for learning..